# Autofac : Resolution from several implementation of a single interface and with different manufacturers

Tags: c#, autofac

Is it possible with Autofac to instantiate classes implementing the same interface but having different constructors and that it deduces which class to instantiate?

```
public sealed class LoginModuleTypeItemViewModel : IInternalModuleTypeItemViewModel
{
    public LoginModuleTypeItemViewModel(LoginModuleTypeExtraModel model)
    {
    }
}

public sealed class TypeObjectModuleTypeItemViewModel : IInternalModuleTypeItemViewModel
{
    public TypeObjectModuleTypeItemViewModel(TypeObjectModuleTypeExtraModel model)
    {
    }
}

builder.RegisterType<TypeObjectModuleItemViewModel>().As<IInternalModuleItemViewModel>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<LoginModuleItemViewModel>().As<IInternalModuleItemViewModel>().SingleInstance();

_container.Resolve<IInternalModuleItemViewModel>(new TypedParameter(model.GetType(), model));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register multiple components ("classes") exposing the same interface ("service") it's *last in wins*. Which means, if you have:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<First>().As<IThing>();
builder.RegisterType<Second>().As<IThing>();
builder.RegisterType<Third>().As<IThing>();
var container = builder.Build();
```

Then when you try to resolve an `IThing` it'll *always* be the last one in.

```cs
var thing = container.Resolve<IThing>();
Assert.IsType<Third>(thing); // this is true
```

It doesn't matter what parameters you pass. If you resolve a single instance of the thing, it'll always be last in wins. There is no "select the thing based on the parameters I pass in." And if you think about it, that makes sense - from a dependency injection / inversion of control standpoint, *the consumer should never know or care what the type is that implements the interface*.

If you extend the logic you're asking for, what if you had this?

```cs
public class First : IThing
{
  public First(Dependency dep) : { }
}

public class Second : IThing
{
  public Second(Dependency dep, OtherDependency other) : { }
}
```

And then you had registered...

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// We can resolve OtherDependency from the container
builder.RegisterType<OtherDependency>();

// The two things we'd pick from
builder.RegisterType<First>().As<IThing>();
builder.RegisterType<Second>().As<IThing>();

var container = builder.Build();

// OtherDependency can come from the container
// but you're providing the Dependency as a parameter
var thing = container.Resolve<IThing>(new TypedParameter(typeof(Dependency), new Dependency());
```

In that example... what type is `thing`? Is it `First` because the only parameter is a `Dependency`? Or is it `Second` because of the standard "last in wins" and because `OtherDependency` can come from the container?

If it's `First` then... what's the use of having a dependency injection container at all, since you're effectively "newing up" a specific type based on the constructor parameters that you have to know anyway?

If it's `Second` then... you're not getting what you're asking for, where you somehow get "the thing matching the constructor parameters."

**I recognize the above doesn't give you an answer** but I'm hoping it gets you to a place where you can understand why maybe what you're asking for isn't something Autofac (or any DI container) can provide - you have a bit of a design problem.

**Your question touches [on one of the Autofac FAQs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) wondering how to "select an implementation by context."**

My guess is that somewhere along the line you have a parameter (or something) and based on that you need to "pick" a different view model type.

The FAQ I linked to explains why that's a design problem and offers some ways to fix it. I won't repeat the whole thing here, but in short:

1. You could redesign/change the interfaces so they aren't identical. If they can't be *treated* as identical, they aren't identical even if they appear to have the same methods.
2. You can update the way you register things that consume your various things so they are somewhat hard-wired to take the type they expect. This is a complex thing involving `ResolvedParameters` and lambda registrations, and there is a working example on that FAQ page to explain it.
3. You could use keyed services to give each vendor's component an ID and then use those keys/IDs in attributes or during manual resolve operations to indicate the thing you want.
4. You could use metadata to attach a vendor ID or some other ID to each vendor's registration to "pick" the right backing component out at runtime.

**[Check out the FAQ for explanations and examples in code.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)** It dives into a deeper explanation on how these options will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works fine. But be sure to correctly resolve with the same type you have in the constructor (if you are registering with `LoginModuleItemViewModel`, the model has to be of type `LoginModuleTypeExtraModel` unless you have a valid constructor with `TypeObjectModuleTypeExtraModel` in `LoginModuleItemViewModel` class).

Comment: When I want to instantiate a `LoginModuleTypeItemViewModel`, "model" is of type 'LoginModuleTypeExtraModel'. Same for `TypeObjectModuleTypeItemViewModel`, "model" is of type `TypeObjectModuleTypeExtraModel`. But this does not currently work, it only considers the last registered type which is `LoginModuleItemViewModel`. Do you have an idea to fix this?

Comment: I think the above answer from @travis-illig clarify things, it's much more of a problem of design than Autofac in the first place.